# How do I use fscanf from the beginning each time when I am in a for / while loop?

Tags: c

How do I use fscanf from the beginning each time when I am in a for loop?

I want to do something like this:

```
 for(i=0; i<5; i++)
      while(fscanf(in, "%d", &number)
            .......
```

Basically, when I use fscanf the first time, it starts scanning from the beginning of the file. I want it to start working from the beginning each time a for loop has been completed, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rewind()` to seek back to the beginning of the file:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    rewind(in);
    while (fscanf(in, "%d", &number)
        .......
```

Note however that this solution only works if the stream is seekable. If it is bound to a regular file, either opened by `fopen` or from a shell redirection, it should be seekable, but if it is bound to a terminal, a pipe or some other character device, `rewind()` may fail. You cannot test this with `rewind()`, but here is an alternative:

```
if (fseek(in, 0L, SEEK_SET)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cannot rewind inut stream\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

A more reliable approach would be to save the values read by `fscanf()` to avoid seeking.

Comment: What if `in == stdin` (unredirected)?

Comment: @GovindParmar: If standard input is coming from a terminal or pipe or other non-seekable device, then the OP is out of luck.  The question is using a file stream which is probably not `stdin`, so there's a decent chance that they are reading a disk file, but it miht be a FIFO, in which case the seek/rewind will fail and input will resume where it left off.  I might be tempted to ask the OP "why don't you remember the input on the first iteration", but there might be a good reason for not doing so.